# Numpy nonzero function not working/minimum of a numpy array without zeros

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to get maximum and minimum values out of a numpy array. In order to have a good overview of the array, I used pandas. Based on this resulting array, I wanted to get a column of maximum and minimum values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TEST = np.load('NPY TEST.npy')
input_array = pd.DataFrame(TEST)
print(input_array)
inputs_max = np.max(input_array, axis=0)
print(inputs_max)
inputs_min = np.min(input_array[np.nonzero(input_array)], axis=0)
print(inputs_min)
```

The problem is that if I use

```
np.min(input_array, axis=0)
```

the resulting column only consists of zeros, although there is not one 0 in my numpy array. So I tried to use the np.nonzero command, which led to many errors:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nonzero'

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your data, why isn't it in your question?

Comment: I can't post an array consisting of 2300 rows and 44 columns. Is this the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Don't need the entire dataset, just a [mcve] should do. See [ask], too.

Comment: @drN15 yes, I guess that's one of the reasons for the downvotes. Furthermore some people tend to check if you accepted answers in previous questions. And if you did not accept a correct answer, chances are high that they will downvote your current question to warn others from putting any effort in answering it. This may not be a good beaviour, but I can understand them... So if you want to increase your chances to get good answers, you should accept the correct answer and upvote (as soon as you have 15 points) good answers.

Comment: I did not know up till now how to accept answers which I just did for all of my asked questions. :) But jesus, as far as I can see this community is not very lenient with new members. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Yep, getting into the community is a hard process. :) Just remember: Most people here are programmers or scientists (including me) and no experts in social behavior (also including me)... ;) But once you get used to it, you can get great help and brilliant input from some of the best programmers (not including me...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just guess what your data is looking like, but I'll give it a try:

```
inputs_min = input_array[input_array != 0.].min(axis=0)
```

Comment: This worked out! Perfect, thank you. I am still confused why the numpy command delivered zeros, though. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You are welcome. You may also accept my answer. Unluckily I have no idea why your approach did not work, since you didn't provide any sample data. But I guess it is because you used numpy functions on dataframes. Most numpy functions can take dataframes as inputs, but some can't. So you should either use the corresponding pandas methods, use "universal features" like conditional bool indexing or extract the numpy arrays of the dataframes like: `np.min(input_array.values[np.nonzero(input_array.values)], axis=0)`

Comment: Yes, I also thought that it has something to do with the interaction of np functions and dataframes. Anyway, it's working now so I guess I will just leave it as it is. You saved my day!